# Error Handling in methods that return account

Tags: error, exception

I have an Apex method that receives an Account record as input and returns Account record. What if an error occurs and i want to return it to the user? I cannot return String, since the method returns Account.
Any ideas ?

Comment: Sounds like the concept you're looking for is _exceptions_, but we'll need more details if you want an accurate answer. Probably the most important detail here is _how does the user end up calling this apex method?_ Is it called as part of a trigger, a visualforce page or lightning component, or something else?

Comment: Hi Derek,For example: 
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<String> matchingService(Account acc) {
        try{//Some code here and return acc; } catch (Exception e){ return ('The following exception has occurred: ' + e.getMessage())                                                                 I cannot save this method cause i cannot return a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, you are looking for a way to return custom error message to User in your Lightning Component. One solution would be to use `AuraHandledException` in your Apex controller. Then you can throw this exception and pass String argument to *helper* which will display it to the User.

Apex controller:

```java
@AuraEnabled public static List<String> matchingService(Account acc) {
    List<String> returnList = new List<String>();
    try {
    //perform some logic on returnList
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new AuraHandledException('You cannot perform this action, error occured: ' + ex.getMessage);
    } 
    return returnList;

}
```

JS Helper:

```js
myFunction: function (component, account) {
        var action = component.get("c.matchingService");
        var account;

        action.setParams({
            "acc": account,
        });

        action.setCallback(this, function (response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                var stringList = response.getReturnValue();
            } else {
                //errorMessage is the String argument of AuraHandledException
                var errorMessage = response.getError()[0].message;
                console.log('Error in matchingService : ' + errorMessage);

                //Handle error - for example show toast with message from Apex controller
                helper.showToast(component, errorMessage);
            }

        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
```